# How can we create editor script for unity component class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, editor

As you folks may know, we can create editor scripts for monobehaviour classes.

I would like to have ability to make editor for Component.
Is it possible?

## Edit 1

I am not asking about Monobehaviour editor class, rather for Component class.

## Edit 2

I am talking about extending by editor exactly Component class.
Exactly write editor for "Component", for having ability make custom inspector for Transform Component, Rigidbody component, etc

Comment: What is a Component? Coz MonoBehaviour is subclass of Component so MB is Component. And you can only work with MB in Editor. You can expose basic non-MB classes in editor in a MB class by adding a reference and Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is a way of overriding the default Unity component editor scripts (a `MonoBehaviour` script is basically a component created by you). I would suggest using the first approach:

- If you simply want to change the way a Unity component is displayed entirely, you can create a new class that derive from the component you want to change and write it a  custom inspector:

  ```
  using UnityEngine;

  #if UNITY_EDITOR
  using UnityEditor;
  #endif

  public class YOUR_CLASS_NAME : THE_CLASS_YOU_DERIVE_FROM
  {
  }

  #if UNITY_EDITOR
  [CustomEditor(typeof(YOUR_CLASS_NAME))]
  public class YOUR_CLASS_NAME_CUSTOM_EDITOR : Editor
  {
      public override void OnInspectorGUI()
      {
          // If you want to display THE_CLASS_YOU_DERIVE_FROM as it is usually on the inspector (doesn't completely work with some components that have "complex" editor)
          base.OnInspectorGUI();

          // Otherwise feel free to do what you want
      }
  }
  #endif
  ```

Note that you can also do it with 2 scripts (simply do not forget to place the editor one under a *.../Editor/...* folder :)

- Remember if this is not to override a Unity default component, you can also use **PropertyDrawers** to change the way serialized property are displayed in the Inspector. You can check [this link](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2012/09/07/property-drawers-in-unity-4/) for more information on it.

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: This is a weird way of doing. The macros are useless since the script should be in Editor folder which is discarded from builds. Also if not in Editor folder, I think Unity does not consider it. The class and the editor version cannot be in the same script (since one has to be in Editor and so on so forth).

Comment: What you have write - it is right to MonoBehaviour classes. But as my question asks: How can we create editor script for unity COMPONENT ?

Comment: @Everts Agreed it seems a bit weird but it's quite useful for very small editor scripts since it avoids creating a separate script. And Unity consider them I can assure you :)

Comment: @VladislavHromyh Well as I said, a component is basically [nothing more than a class](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingComponents.html): when you write a new class that derives from `MonoBehaviour`, you create a new component (`MonoBehaviour : Behaviour : Component`). That being said I'm not sure you can just simply override the way Unity display these class in the inspector: this is why I suggested this simple approach that can fit in a single script (a `Monobehaviour` class without any `Start`, `Update`, etc... behave like a `Component` (at least I think)).

Comment: It wont be working, if YOUR_CLASS_NAME  wil be Component. That's what I try to do. Inspector for all Components.

Comment: Well as far as I know, there is no way to directly do something like `[CustomEditor(typeof(Component))]` (this will throw error and not display anything).